# Routing problem in ActiveScaffold with Rails 3.0

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

I'm trying out ActiveScaffold with Rails 3.0, still trying to get it to work at all. I'm getting an error

```
No route matches {:active_scaffold=>true, :action=>"show_search", :controller=>"locations"}
```

when I browse to http://localhost:3000/locations. I have "resources :locations, :active_scaffold => true" in my routes.rb, but I don't know if that is the right syntax for Rails 3.0.

I have never used ActiveScaffold and am not committed to it, so another question is whether there are better alternatives -- or does that depend on the specifics of the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when folowing instructions on github. Just use `rails g active_scaffold XXXXX` command and it will also write your route.Also you should be using this [active_scaffold fork](http://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold)

Answer (score 6):

There is apparently a new version of the Rails 3.0 fork of ActiveScaffold, or perhaps just new documentation I found. The routing should be

```
  resources :locations do as_routes end
```

If you generate a model using AS from the beginning, it inserts this for you.